# Tomcat on Azure VM using terraform?

Tags: azure, tomcat, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I've been searching for an ansswer but been unable to find anything. Is there a way to install tomcat on Azure virtual machine using terraform? All the examples I've seen are thro the portal interface. I would like to deploy the code several times and would therefore like tomcat to be included on the VM when it's created via terraform.

Comment: Can you be more specific? A typical solution is using the CustomScript extension, but it is not clear what is your hurdle.

Comment: You mean How install install Tomcat on Azure VM via Terraform (or Tomcat)?

Comment: Oh now I see why it's confusing. Yes it was supposed to be how to install tomcat on Azure VM via terraform.

Comment: @MoaEkberg If the answer is helpful ore for more help, please let me know.

Comment: We decided to solve it by using ansible.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure VM, it usually uses an extension to install software in the VM no matter deploy it or finishing. See [Extension in Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine_extension.html).